# With PowerShell and ReportingService2010, how to change empty shared datasource or custom datasource to shared datasource?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm quite in an impasse here. I started writing a script with PowerShell to handle setting Shared Datasources to all the reports of a folder.

My logic :
For each report in the folder and For each datasource of the report :

> If the datasource name matches with the one to be replace
> 1 : If its reference is already set up : replace it with the shared one
> 2 : If its a Custom Datasource : replace it with the shared one
> 3 : If its reference is empty : replace it with the shared one

Case 1 works perfectly, while Case 2 and Case 3 fail. I don't understand why for the first case it accept a single element while for the other, it fails telling me that it needs an array :

```
Impossible de convertir l'argument «DataSources» (valeur «SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource») de «SetItemDataSources
» en type «SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource[]»: «Impossible de convertir la valeur «
SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource» du type «SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource» en type «
SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource[]».»
Au caractère Ligne:87 : 1
+ $proxy.SetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path, $newDataSource);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Here's the entire code I came up with (its verbose but I think it helps readability) :

```
# Usage : SetConnection "msbireports" "/2134_DELIVRI/Test/PS1" "EDUCFI_SSAS" "/2134_DELIVRI/Test/PS1/Datasources/EDUCFI_SSAS.rds" true
function SetConnection(
    $reportServerName = $(throw "reportServerName is required."),
    $serverPath = $(throw "serverPath is required."),
    $connectionName = $(throw "connectionName is required."),
    $toConnection = $(throw "toConnection is required."),
    $replaceCustom = $(throw "replaceCustom is required.")
    )
{
    Write-Host "> Connecting to $reportServerName" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $reportServerUri = "https://{0}/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx" -f $reportServerName
    $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerUri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential
    Write-Host "  Done !" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host ""
    
    # List everything on the Report Server, not recursively, but filter to keep Reports
    Write-Host "> Getting Items from $serverPath"
    $items = $proxy.ListChildren($serverPath, $false) | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "Report"}
    
    Write-Host "Found $($items.Length) reports..."
    Write-Host ""
    # Loop through reports and data sources
    Foreach($ssrsItem in $items)
    {
        # Handling report.rdl...
        Write-Host "> Handling $($ssrsItem.Path).rdl"
        
        # Get Datasources having the wanted name
        $dsItems = $proxy.GetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path)
        $dsTarget = $proxy.GetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $connectionName}
        if ($dsTarget.Length -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host ">> Skipped : no DataSource named $connectionName" -ForegroundColor Gray
            Write-Host ""
        }
        else
        {
            Foreach($dsItem in $dsItems)
            {
                if ($dsItem.Name -eq $connectionName)
                {
                    # Check if the object has a reference or not (i.e. : its filled shared datasource or not : custom dataset OR empty filled shared datasource)
                    if($dsItem.Item.PSObject.Properties.Match('Reference').Count)
                    {
                        # Does the shared Datasource already points to the good one ?
                        if ($dsItem.Item.Reference -eq $toConnection)
                        {
                            Write-Host ">> Nothing done : $connectionName already set up as $toConnection" -ForegroundColor Gray
                            Write-Host ""
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            # Shared Datasource with an already filled Shared Datasource which points diffrently : change it.
                            Write-Host ">> Changing $connectionName from $($dsItem.Item.Reference) to $toConnection..." -ForegroundColor Gray
                            $dsItem.Item.Reference = $toConnection;
                            $proxy.SetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path, $dsItem);
                            Write-Host "  Done!" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Write-Host ""
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        # Two cases here : 1. Custom Datasource or 2. SharedDatasource but empty or 
                        # Check for Custom Datasource (has a property called Enabled which ShareDatasource has not)
                        if($dsItem.Item.PSObject.Properties.Match('Enabled').Count)
                        {
                            if ($replaceCustom -eq "replace")
                            {
                                Write-Host ">> Changing Custom Connection $connectionName to a Shared one pointing to $toConnection..." -ForegroundColor Gray

                                $newDataSource = New-Object("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource")
                                $newDataSource.Name = $connectionName
                                $newDataSource.Item = New-Object ("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSourceReference")
                                $newDataSource.Item.Reference = $toConnection
                                
                                $proxy.SetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path, $newDataSource);

                                Write-Host "  DOES NOT WORK !" -ForegroundColor RED
                                Write-Host ""
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Write-Host ">> Nothing done : $connectionName set up as a Custom Connection, but was told not to change it" -ForegroundColor Gray
                                Write-Host ""
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host ">> OF TYPE SHARED... But not really ???"
                            $newDataSource = New-Object("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource")
                            $newDataSource.Name = $connectionName
                            $newDataSource.Item = New-Object ("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSourceReference")
                            $newDataSource.Item.Reference = $toConnection

                            $proxy.SetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path, $newDataSource);
                            Write-Host "  DOES NOT WORK !" -ForegroundColor RED
                            Write-Host ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

SetConnection "msbireports" "/2134_DELIVRI/Test/PS1" "EDUCFI_SSAS" "/1446_EDUCFI/Datasources/EDUCFI_SSAS" "replace"
```

This is driving me nuts. I also tried to do this differently, that is building an array of DataSources and at the end of the report's handling pushing it to with `SetItemDataSources` but everytime, those two cases failed, with a weird error, telling me it can't convert a DataSource to.. a DataSource. (?!)

My sanity begs for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing a bit with the code, I changed my method and built an array containing already valid datasources and new ones and changing them at the very end. This should be better but still, I still have this strange casting error...

Here's the new code :

```
function SetConnection(
    $reportServerName = $(throw "reportServerName is required."),
    $serverPath = $(throw "serverPath is required."),
    $connectionName = $(throw "connectionName is required."),
    $toConnection = $(throw "toConnection is required."),
    $replaceCustom = $(throw "replaceCustom is required.")
    )
{
    Write-Host "> Connecting to $reportServerName" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $reportServerUri = "https://{0}/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx" -f $reportServerName
    $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerUri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential
    Write-Host "  Done !" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host ""
    
    # List everything on the Report Server, not recursively, but filter to keep Reports
    Write-Host "> Getting Items from $serverPath"
    $items = $proxy.ListChildren($serverPath, $false) | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "Report"}
    
    Write-Host "Found $($items.Length) reports..."
    Write-Host ""
    # Loop through reports and data sources
    Foreach($ssrsItem in $items)
    {
        # Handling report.rdl...
        Write-Host "> Handling $($ssrsItem.Path).rdl"
        
        # Get Datasources having the wanted name
        $dsItems = $proxy.GetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path)
        $dsUpdated = @()
        $dsTarget = $proxy.GetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $connectionName}
        if ($dsTarget.Length -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host ">> Skipped : no DataSource named $connectionName" -ForegroundColor Gray
            Write-Host ""
        }
        else
        {
            Foreach($dsItem in $dsItems)
            {
                if ($dsItem.Name -ne $connectionName)
                {
                     $dsUpdated += $dsItem;
                }
                else
                {
                    # Check if the object has a reference or not (i.e. : its filled shared datasource or not : custom dataset OR empty filled shared datasource)
                    if($dsItem.Item.PSObject.Properties.Match('Reference').Count)
                    {
                        # Does the shared Datasource already points to the good one ?
                        if ($dsItem.Item.Reference -eq $toConnection)
                        {
                            Write-Host ">> Nothing done : $connectionName already set up as $toConnection" -ForegroundColor Gray
                            Write-Host ""
                            $dsUpdated += $dsItem;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            # Shared Datasource with an already filled Shared Datasource which points diffrently : change it.
                            Write-Host ">> Changing $connectionName from $($dsItem.Item.Reference) to $toConnection..." -ForegroundColor Gray
                            Write-Host ""
                            $dsItem.Item.Reference = $toConnection;                 
                            $dsUpdated += $dsItem;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        # Two cases here : 1. Custom Datasource or 2. SharedDatasource but empty or 
                        # Check for Custom Datasource (has a property called Enabled which ShareDatasource has not)
                        if($dsItem.Item.PSObject.Properties.Match('Enabled').Count)
                        {
                            if ($replaceCustom -eq "replace")
                            {
                                Write-Host ">> Changing Custom Connection $connectionName to a Shared one pointing to $toConnection..." -ForegroundColor Gray
                                Write-Host ""
                                $newDataSource = New-Object("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource")
                                $newDataSource.Name = $connectionName
                                $newDataSource.Item = New-Object ("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSourceReference")
                                $newDataSource.Item.Reference = $toConnection
                                $dsUpdated += $newDataSource;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Write-Host ">> Nothing done : $connectionName set up as a Custom Connection, but was told not to change it" -ForegroundColor Gray
                                Write-Host ""
                                $dsUpdated += $dsItem;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host ">> OF TYPE SHARED... But not really ???"
                            Write-Host ""
                            $newDataSource = New-Object("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSource")
                            $newDataSource.Name = $connectionName
                            $newDataSource.Item = New-Object ("SSRS.ReportingService2010.DataSourceReference")
                            $newDataSource.Item.Reference = $toConnection
                            $dsUpdated += $newDataSource;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $proxy.SetItemDataSources($ssrsItem.Path, $dsUpdated);  
            
        }
    }
}
```